# Laravel database search or query convert

Tags: database, laravel, search

Hi I have a database table with 10 columns, with name'id','col1'~'col9',I search through the internet, and could not get an idea how to search the data.
For example, I type 'abc' as search content to search through the database columns(no limit to single column) . I tried to use foreach($results as $key=>$value and check the $vlue with the input, but then have no idea to put the data into the array as an pure multidimensional array.
I have two thoughts about the way to search
1. I convert all the database data to an multi-dimensional array(not object in array) so that I could use strpos to loop again to check for the data I have
2.I will use foreach($results as $key=>$value) compare value and save this object into new array.

Could anyone educate me which way is easier? As later I am going to export and import csv files, I prefer 1st option. so that array will be easily exported to csv.

```
    public function search(Request $request)
{

      $search = $request->input('searchcontent');
     $results = DB::table('records')->get();
     $records=[];
     $i=0;

     foreach($results as $key=>$value)

     {
         if($search==$value)
         {
            $records[$i]=[$key=>$value];
            $i++;
         }
     }




    return view('home',['records'=>$records]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i would look at performance implications, must you search all 10 columns from 1 search query because this will be expensive and be reaaaaallly slow once you have millions of records.

Secondly have you added indexes to all of your searchable columns so that the database can make much faster searches.

and lastly i would avoid getting data and looping where you can, sometimes it is ok if you are not performing expensive operations within the loop.

for searching a column you could do

```
Model::where('column1', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchterm.'%')->orWhere('column2', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchterm.'%') etc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was trying to check if my database contain the keyword I typed in the form and return all the records(no matter which column it is). In CSV file, I could do it just check string position if found ,put the whole record in array .but database seems not able to do in this way....